# Handle errors when loading content into a Kendo UI KendoWindow

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a `KendoWindow` that loads content into an iFrame from a JSP.
I've attached error-handlers at every position yet when the JSP isn't available, none of these error handlers are called.
What is the proper way to handle errors when loading `content` into a KendoWindow?

```
     win.kendoWindow({
        width : "860px",
        modal : true,
        height : "680px",
        iframe : true,
        resizable : false,
        content : { 
            url: "access/lookup/Source.jsp", 
            failure: function(err) {
                console.log(e.status);
                console.log(e.xhr);
            }, 
            error: function(err) {
                console.log(e.status);
                console.log(e.xhr);
            }
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(e.status);
            console.log(e.xhr);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the [source code](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.window.js), you see:

```
if (!showIframe) {
    // perform AJAX request
    that._ajaxRequest(options);
} else {
    iframe = element.find("." + KCONTENTFRAME)[0];
    // Edited for clarity
    iframe.src = url || iframe.src;
}
```

`showIframe`, if not set in options, is defined as:

```
showIframe = !isLocalUrl(url);
```

So only the code execution branch that does the ajax request uses your error handlers. The `else` branch just does an iframe and lets the browser handle it.

Adding `iframe: false` to the content options, as shown [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window/configuration/content#contenttemplate), should help.